# Como tirar Screenshot no windows 10 com visual basic .net

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Olá amigos estou tentando tira print no windows 10 acontece que o mesmo dica com tela preta, não tirando print.Estou usando visual basic .net

Public Sub printar()

```
    Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Bounds.Width, Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(Bounds.X, Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)

    PictureBox1.Image = Tela.RetornaImagemControle(TextBox2.Text, bounds)


End Sub
```

Comment: Aqui para mim funcionou, só tive que alterar a úlima linha para `PictureBox1.Image = screenshot`.

Comment: No windows 10 tela fica preta, ou seja a print sai preta, aguardo ajuda obrigado...

Comment: O meu Windows é 10 também, e funcionou só alterando essa última linha, como eu disse. O que essa função `Tela.RetornaImagemControle()` faz? Você não parece estar usando em nenhum lugar o bitmap gerado.